# Getting "argument out of range" when trying to turn a duration into milliseconds in Rails 4

Tags: parsing, ruby-on-rails-4, time, duration

I’m using Rails 4.2.4.  I have the below method for converting a time (duration) to milliseconds …

```
Time.parse(convert_to_hrs(duration)).seconds_since_midnight * 1000
```

in which the method “convert_to_hrs” is defined as

```
    def convert_to_hrs(string)
      case string.count(':')
      when 0
        '00:00:' + string.rjust(2, '0')
      when 1
        '00:' + string
      else
        string
      end
    end
```

However, if the duration is something really big (e.g. “34:13:00” -- read:  34 hours, 13 minutes, and zero seconds), the above fails with the error

```
Error during processing: argument out of range
/Users/mikea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:302:in `local'
/Users/mikea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:302:in `make_time'
/Users/mikea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:366:in `parse'
/Users/mikea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/my_service.rb:25:in `block in process_page_data'
/Users/mikea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/my_service.rb:22:in `each'
/Users/mikea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/my_service.rb:22:in `process_page_data'
```

How do I rewrite my first line to accurately convert duration into milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you're always going to be using a hours:minutes:seconds format, but the number in each field isn't guaranteed to be inside the 'normal' range (e.g. 0-23 for hours, 0-59 for minutes, etc), then you're probably best off doing it 'manually' using something like this:

```
def duration_in_milliseconds(input)
  h, m, s = input.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  (h.hours + m.minutes + s.seconds) * 1000
end

puts duration_in_milliseconds('34:13:00') #=> 123180000
```

Note that this only works with ActiveSupport, but you have that, since you've specified Rails. Also, this assumes you're always getting all three terms (e.g. 5 seconds is 00:00:05). The full setup that accepts shorter strings as well would want to also use your convert_to_hrs method.

Note also that this works even if formatting isn't strictly 'time-like', as long as you have consistent colons as seperators:

```
puts duration_in_milliseconds('1:1:5') #=> 3665000
```

The [`Numeric#hours`, `Numeric#minutes` and `Numeric#seconds`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Numeric.html) methods are provided by ActiveSupport, as part of [active_support/core-ext/time.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5144d8a5529baebdaf76dbf253d1d6f2d8689b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb). They aren't particularly documented, but they return [ActiveSupport::Duration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) objects, which have fancy methods for interacting with Time and Date issues like `5.days.ago`, but when treated as an integer are effectively a number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`Time.parse` is throwing error, becuase values you passing in `duration` variable is out of range.

For Ex:
`Time.parse(convert_to_hrs('59:59'))` as per your written `code`, it's return `2016-07-27 00:59:59 +0530`

Here the value `59:59` consider as `minutes:seconds`, so if you pass the value `60:60` then it will raise the error `argument out of range`

[Here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/parse/class) is the official documentation for `parse` method of `Time`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I understand why the error is happneing but I don't understand how to write a statement that will properly return duration in milliseconds given the value I listed.  How do I do taht?

Comment: what is the value for `duration`?

Comment: Go with the example in my question, which is “44:09”

Comment: I already tried, it's working and result is `2.2.2 :015 > Time.parse(convert_to_hrs("44:09")).seconds_since_midnight * 1000
 => 2649000.0 

`

Comment: If you replace `44:09` to `60:00` it will raise an error `ArgumentError: argument out of range` as I explained

Comment: You are right -- 44:09 works and 60:00 does not.  I hvae edited my question.  I would like to know how to get this to work for 60:00 .

Comment: as per document `parse` method will not allow to perform this operation, if you want to use `60:00` you have to convert it to another format. like: `60:00` mins to `01:00:00` hour

Comment: You are righit about converting the format.  However, if the format is valid, e.g. "34:13:00" (thirty four hours, 13 minutes, and zero seconds), I get the error.  Note I don't care about using parse -- any method that turns the string into milliseconds is fine by me.